# Learning quantum CS

Tags: reference-request, big-list, quantum-computing, soft-question

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [What is the quantum computational model?](https://cstheory.stackexchange.com/questions/482/what-is-the-quantum-computational-model)

What is the best way to study quantum branch of CS for the person with rather advanced background in classical CS? Does one need to study quantum mechanics?